# Spring Reactive- How to update document in capped collection in Mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a capped collection in mongodb and I'm streaming documents. I can create new document with spring but I can not update any document.

code that I used for updating document

```
@GetMapping("/tweetedit/{text}")
Mono<Tweets> edittweet(@PathVariable String text){
    Mono<Tweets> tweet2 = repo.findById("5cc206a32f6b6401cc9fb591");
    return tweet2.doOnSuccess(findtweet -> {
        findtweet.setText(text);
        repo.save(findtweet).subscribe();
    });
}
```

Is there any way for updating document in capped collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flatMap` instead of `doOnSuccess` with `subscribe`:

```
repo.findById("5cc206a32f6b6401cc9fb591")
  .flatMap(tweet -> {
    tweet.setText(text);
    return repo.save(tweet);
  });
```